# BIND configured, DNS configured. No joy!

Tags: networking, dns, kvm-virtualization, nginx

I have a GoDaddy domain, I've adding host names (ns1, ns2 of the domain through GD), I've pointed the name servers to my VPS server IP. So we are ok so far, great.

I've resorted to install VestaCP on Ubuntu 14.04 x64 KVM VPS. I've used VestaCP to change default name servers to ns1, ns2. I've added the domain using Vesta. I haven't manually added it as a virtual site through nginx as I presume Vesta does that?

I've yet to edit BIND9 DNS manually on this build, as previously I built the config using zones/master config file, but it didn't resolve.

Of course, the server can be connected to by IP, however my domain will not resolve at all!

Any help?

Comment: "I've pointed the name servers...": does that mean that your VPS is the NS for your domain?

Comment: Both in GDaddy panel - as otherwise I couldn't point it to my server without using free DNS tools & I didn't want to do that. So I made my VPS the NS of my domain. Is this the wrong way around?